# Windows 10 lost administrator rights and cant insert administrator password to change settings

Tags: passwords, windows-10, administrator

I have changed my username from netplwiz.

I have restarted the pc and now I am a guest account.

I go to change settings but I can't insert the admin password!

I have only option to insert a smart card and I cannot enter a password!

[image]

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: If you can start the machine using a Windows 8 ISO you'll be able to reset the password/reactivate your account/put it back to original username. Alternatively, there is a hack that swaps the accessibility wizard with CMD and it runs as system user where you can enable the Administrator account and set its password, thus giving you access to your system to fix your account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved by inserting a disk installation of Windows 10 I could run the System Restore and go back to the time before you change the username thank you all for the interesting replies that might be useful in the future.

Many thanks 
Massimo :)

Answer (score 1):

This should be able to be fixed by booting into **recovery mode**. (Either by inserting your OS disc or by Start > Shift+Restart)

In the command prompt, type the following commands and then restart your computer:

```
net user [your username] [new password]
net localgroup administrators [your username] /add
```